# How to read xml elements of same node to dataset?

Tags: xml, dataset

I have a xml file like this:

```
<NewDataSet>
    <Communications>
       <ModelNumber>0x01</ModelNumber>
       <ParamName>BaudRate</ParamName>
       <ParamValues>
          <ParamValue>9600</ParamValue>
          <ParamValue>19200</ParamValue>
          <ParamValue>115200</ParamValue>
       </ParamValues>
       <DefaultValue>502</DefaultValue>
       <MaxValue></MaxValue>
       <MinValue></MinValue>
   </Communications>
</NewDataSet>
```

I tried this to read data from xml to dataset:

```
    public ObservableCollection<Communication> GetCommunications()
    {
        DataSet ds = StoreDbDataSet.ReadDataSet();
        ObservableCollection<Communication> communications = new ObservableCollection<Communication>();
        foreach (DataRow communicationRow in ds.Tables["Communications"].Rows)
        {
            communications.Add(new Communication((UInt16)communicationRow["ModelNumber"], communicationRow["ParamName"].ToString(),
                    communicationRow["ParamValue"].ToString(), communicationRow["DefaultValue"].ToString(), communicationRow["MaxValue"].ToString(),
                    communicationRow["MinValue"].ToString()));
        }
        return communications;
    }
```

But this can not read the `ParamValue` to the dataset, what should I do to fix this?Thanks in advance!